# Python value in dictionary changed without update

Tags: python, dictionary

I try this simple code:

```
def chage_value(dict, key):
    dict[key] = 123
    return dict


my_dict = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}

print(my_dict)

chage_value(my_dict, 'a')

print(my_dict)
```

This gives me output:

```
{'a': 1, 'b': 2}
{'a': 123, 'b': 2}
```

Why ‘a’ value changed? I didn’t do something like my_dict = chage_value(my_dict, 'a')

Comment: `dict[key] = 123` this statement changes the dictionary in-place

Comment: Yes I understand how this happened, but I don’t understand WHY this happened?

Comment: The dict is passed into the function by reference, so `dict` inside the function and `my_dict` outside both refer to the same object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were mutating the arguments thats why, for example see this

```py
def add_to(num, target=[]):
    target.append(num)
    return target

add_to(1)
# Output: [1]

add_to(2)
# Output: [1, 2]

add_to(3)
# Output: [1, 2, 3]
```

You might be expecting that a fresh list would be created when you call `add_to`, but thats not the case. You mutate the argument, this is what you want to do when you don't want it to mutate the argument

```py
from copy import deepcopy
def foo(some_var):
    some_var_ = deepcopy(some_var)
    ...
    return some_var_
```

Here you mutate the copy of `some_var` instead of the original.

You can see here what are the other mutable things. https://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/mutation.html#mutation

Comment: Thank you all for your answers, now it’s clear

Comment: @garikf If you find it helpful you can click on the checkmark option on the answer near the upvote button